Reqnroll extract step definitions
please tell me how i can extract all possible steps in Reqnroll, I looked at the documentation but did not find this, now in our tests steps are extracted using reflection, but there must be a normal way to do it?

Can you clarify what you mean? What do you mean by "extract all possible steps?"

I see a lot of questionst tagged [tag:specflow] and [tag:reqnroll], but I don't understand the connection between the two. I thought you used one or the other. Are you migrating from SpecFlow to Reqnroll?

Reqnroll based on Specflow...I solved my problem through reflection

There's nothing wrong with answering your own question. As projects move from SpecFlow, others might run into the same issue. You can write an answer and accept it.
